# Slideshow that increases z-index and decreases opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index, opacity

First time posting, please bear with me.

I'm trying to create a slideshow that:

- assigns a z-index to each `<section>`
- sets all slides with an opacity of 0.7
- assigns the currently top slide an opacity of 1

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="slides">
  <section class="slide">
    <article>
      <h1>6</h1>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="slide">
    <article>
      <h1>5</h1>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="slide">
    <article>
      <h1>4</h1>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="slide">
    <article>
      <h1>3</h1>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="slide">
    <article>
      <h1>2</h1>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="slide">
    <article>
      <h1>1</h1>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
<div id="prev">
  <a href="#previous">&larr;</a>
</div>
<div id="next">
  <a href="#next">&rarr;</a>
</div>
```

Here is the JS so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var z = 0;
  var inAnimation = false;

  $('section.slide').each(function() {
    z++;
    $(this).css('z-index', z);
  });

  function swapFirstLast(isFirst) {
    if(inAnimation) return false;
    else inAnimation = true;

    var processZindex, direction, newZindex, inDeCrease;

    if(isFirst) {
      processZindex = z; direction = '-'; newZindex = 1; inDeCrease = 1;
    } else {
      processZindex = 1; direction = ''; newZindex = z; inDeCrease = -1;
    }

    $('section.slide').each(function() {
      if($(this).css('z-index') == processZindex) {
        $(this).animate({ 'top' : direction + $(this).height() + 'px' }, 'slow', function() {
          $(this).css('z-index', newZindex)
          .animate({ 'top' : '0' }, 'slow', function() {
            inAnimation = false;
          });
        });
      } else {
        $(this).animate({ 'top' : '0' }, 'slow', function() {
          $(this).css('z-index', parseInt($(this).css('z-index')) + inDeCrease);
        });
      }

      return false;
    }

    $('#next a').click(function() {
      return swapFirstLast(true);
    });

    $('#prev a').click(function() {
      return swapFirstLast(false);
    });
  });
});
```

I thought I could insert the following code into the script:

```
if($(this).css('z-index') == processZindex) {
  $(this).css('opacity', 1);
} else {
  $(this).css('opacity', 0.7);
}
```

The problem is I can't seem to get the opacity at 1 to keep up with the z-index value of 6. So I thought about writing `$(this).css('z-index') == processZindex` as `$(this).css('z-index') != 6` but the issue occurs.

Is there a simpler way to code this?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you want.  You want the slides to be stacked?  And then shuffle up/down with z-index and opacity?  And why is z-index important here?

Comment: Your code seems a bit convoluted, as Jeff B said, can you explain in more detail the effect your trying to achieve?

Comment: The z-index is important for the effect I want to achieve: the slides layer on top of each other, with the slides behind the top one slightly translucent. Like a stack of pancakes with the top pancake having an opacity of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used the ordering of elements instead of z-index, using `appendTo`,`preprendTo`:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/RAT8N/1/

I couldn't decide if one function or separate functions was better.  Here is two separate functions:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/5LJcA/3/

Is that what you are going for?

Comment: I'm trying out the code you suggested and my slides are pushing lower on the browser window every time I cycle through all 6. What references (books, sites) could I use to learn how to write code similar to what you produced? You and trickyzter weren't kidding about my code being convoluted.

Comment: You mean their top offset increases?  What browser?  Does it do it in my example, or just when you copy-paste my code?

Comment: Also, practice-practice-practice.  I learned jQuery by playing with it, I didn't use any references other than the jQuery site and SO answers.

Comment: Here is my [test](http://jhames.com/test/). I'm hoping to center the content in the browser, and the magic number for the pixel shift is 136 px. I'm not sure where the script finds that value.

Comment: Ah, actually, you will find that pixel shift changes depending on the document height.  Your version has a wrapper div.  Change the `.offset()` to `.position()` which gets the position relative to its parent, rather than the document.  Also, you might want to add `overflow: hidden` to your `body`.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/gsy8W/embedded/result/

Comment: Also, your `svg`s made me think I was doing something wrong, because they are also semi-transparent. :)

Comment: Using `.position()` solved the issue! I can't thank you enough. I'm going to update my SVGs to set them all solid white. Why the use of `overflow:hidden` to `body`, incidentally?

Comment: If you don't have `overeflow: hidden`, your scrollbars will show up and move as the svgs go off the page on the top or bottom.  Also, do you mind accepting my answer? (Click the check mark on the left of my answer).